# How to display categories that have posts with specific tag in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, tags

I want to create a sidebar that only displays Categories that have a post with chosen tag.

So if you chose the tag "car" the sidebar will only display categories that have posts tagged with the tag "car".

When you then choose that category from the sidebar it will keep the selected tag and only show the post with this tag.

Hope you have some suggestions for me.

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirements WordPress provides several plugins which can be used according to your need
One such plugin i found on word press is

```
Category Posts in Custom Menu
```

using this you can list your post under different tags in sidebar
You may read the installation and usage in details for this plugin